# Oracle SQL - Conditional aggregation pivot with multiple header

Tags: sql, oracle, header, pivot

This question is much enhanced version to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50537526/oracle-sql-pivot-table-rows-to-column-and-use-sub-query-in-pivot/50538017?noredirect=1#comment88127266_50538017) and hope I get some help here. I have below table/View with sample or dummy data:
TABLE/VIEW name: **CUST_HOTEL_VIEW**

```
+----+----------------+---------------+---------------+--------+---------------+
| ID |    Customer    |     Hotel     | Booked_Status | Budget | Booked_Amount |
+----+----------------+---------------+---------------+--------+---------------+
|  1 | John Smith     | Beverly Hills | Booked        |   2000 |           500 |
|  2 | John Smith     | Royal Palms   | Cancelled     |   3000 |               |
|  3 | Marilyn Lawson | Beverly Hills |               |    500 |               |
|  4 | John Smith     | Ritz-Carlton  |               |    250 |               |
|  5 | Marilyn Lawson | Royal Palms   |               |    700 |               |
|  6 | Sarah Elliot   | Royal Palms   | Cancelled     |   1500 |               |
|  7 | Sarah Elliot   | Ritz-Carlton  | Booked        |   2000 |          1500 |
|  8 | Sarah Elliot   | Royal Palms   | Booked        |   2500 |          1000 |
+----+----------------+---------------+---------------+--------+---------------+
```

Need help to get below output with multiple header i.e., to get count of customer and sum of budget per hotel (Below is the output from excel pivot table):
[image]

Am using Oracle 12c R1 db and if I get query with conditional aggregation that helps; as I found this simpler and much easier to understand.

<s>I tried below query to get count and booked amount:</s>

```
SELECT COALESCE(CUSTOMER, 'Grand Total') as " " ,
       (case when COUNT(booked_status) != 0 then count(booked_status) else null end) as "# Booked",
sum(case when booked_status = 'Booked' THEN booking_amount ELSE null END) as "Booked Amount"
FROM CUST_HOTEL_VIEW
GROUP BY ROLLUP(CUSTOMER)
order by CUSTOMER
```

and got below output:

```
+--------------+----------+---------------+
|              | # Booked | Booked Amount |
+--------------+----------+---------------+
| John Smith   |        1 |           500 |
| Sarah Elliot |        2 |          2500 |
| Grand Total  |        3 |          3000 |
+--------------+----------+---------------+
```

But was unable to get output with merged header.

I appreciate any help with this.

Thanks,
Richa

**UPDATE:**
Adding final output table section below:
**FINAL OUTPUT TABLE:**

```
+--------------+---------------+--------+-------------+--------+--------------+--------+-------------+------+
|   CUSTOMER   |      Beverly Hills     |      Royal Palms     |      Ritz-Carlton     |      Grand Total   |
+--------------+---------------+--------+-------------+--------+--------------+--------+-------------+------+
|              | Count         | Sum    | Count       | Sum    | Count        | Sum    | Count       | Sum  |
+--------------+---------------+--------+-------------+--------+--------------+--------+-------------+------+
| Sarah Elliot | 0             | (null) | 1           | 2500   | 1            | 2000   | 2           | 4500 |
| John Smith   | 1             | 2000   | 0           | (null) | 0            | (null) | 1           | 2000 |
| Grand Total  | 1             | 2000   | 1           | 2500   | 1            | 2000   | 3           | 6500 |
+--------------+---------------+--------+-------------+--------+--------------+--------+-------------+------+
```

Comment: In SQL you decide, what columns you fill, when you write the query. It is afaik impossible to get 15 colums because there are 15 different hotels in your result set. I finish such tasks with a table calculation program

Comment: F.e. Excel Pivot Table

Comment: @am2, thanks for the prompt response. I appreciate. Assuming table only have 3 or 4 hotels, in that sense is it still impossible to have this with sql query? I would like to know with SQL how to achieve multiple row header with grouping. If the query works for my sample data provided, that's more than enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

From the question's description I can not infer what exactly is the requirement, but it seems to me that you are looking for something like that:

---

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dbd49/7

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT CUSTOMER, HOTEL, BUDGET
  FROM Table1
  WHERE BOOKED_STATUS = 'Booked'
)
PIVOT (
  count(*) as cnt, sum(BUDGET) as budget
  FOR HOTEL IN ('Beverly Hills','Royal Palms','Ritz-Carlton')
 )
```

---

```
|     CUSTOMER | 'Beverly Hills'_CNT | 'Beverly Hills'_BUDGET | 'Royal Palms'_CNT | 'Royal Palms'_BUDGET | 'Ritz-Carlton'_CNT | 'Ritz-Carlton'_BUDGET |
|--------------|---------------------|------------------------|-------------------|----------------------|--------------------|-----------------------|
| Sarah Elliot |                   0 |                 (null) |                 1 |                 2500 |                  1 |                  2000 |
|   John Smith |                   1 |                   2000 |                 0 |               (null) |                  0 |                (null) |
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Am sorry if my question was confusing. Answser you suggested is pretty close but I want header as merged. 
Since am not able to post table in comment. Am updating the OP under section "FINAL TABLE OUTPUT"

Comment: This is not possible to do in ordinary SQL, you need to do it at presentation layer of your application (whatever it is - java, c#, excel etc), not at the database side..

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and answer. I appreciate. Can you please let me know if I can use sub query in this line:
`FOR HOTEL IN ('Beverly Hills','Royal Palms','Ritz-Carlton')`. I tried subquery and getting an error

Comment: No, a subquery canot be used, pivot is a static-SQL. You can use subqueries in XML PIVOT, see this article: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html, but this generates XML results, not table-like resultset. You can also use dynamic SQL to generate dynamically query, but this is a huge topic.